# Video packet capture over multiple IP cameras

Tags: c, pthreads, rtsp, ip-camera

We are working on a C language application which is simple RTSP/RTP client to record video from Axis a number of Cameras. We launch a pthread for each of the camera which establishes the RTP session and begin to record the packets captured using the recvfrom() call.
A single camera single pthread records fine for well over a day without issues.

But testing with more cameras available,about 25(so 25 pthreads), the recording to file goes fine for like 15 to 20 mins and then the recording just stops. The application still keeps running. Its been over a month and a half we have been trying with varied implementations but nothing seems to help. Please provide suggestions.

We are using CentOS 5 platform

Comment: it sounds like a  deadlock issue:

1) dose it happens with fewer then 25 threads ?

2) when it happens what are your threads doing at time ?

Comment: What plataform are you working on?
Which packet capture libraries are you using?

Comment: This is not much information to go on.  I would suggest an alternative implementation where there is one thread that processes all cameras using select() or poll() to control flow.

Comment: too little description for helpful advice. what about showing some program logic here?

Comment: We do not use any packet capture libraries, just the linux socket api.

The problem begins to occur with more than 12 cameras..

also as "atlpeg" says I also have a single threaded version where the cameras are polled one by one
in a for() loop it does improve the performance for 25 cameras, also the RTP packets were passed to a msgq and handled by another writetofile thread The issue here was significant packet loss and the recorded video is corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Define "record"  Does that mean write data to a file?  How do you control access to the file?

You can't have several threads all trying to write at the exact same time.  So the comment by Alon  seems to be pertinent.  Your write access control machanism has problems.

Comment: yes Jim record->write the data to a file in the HardDisk
Each camera writes to a separate file

Answer (score 0):

```
void *IPThread(void *ptr)
{
//Establish RTSP session
//Bind to RTP ports(video)
//Increase Socket buffer size to 625KB

record_fd=open(record_name, O_CREAT|O_RDWR|O_TRUNC, 0777);
while(1)
{
    if(poll(RTP/RTCP ports)) //a timeout value of 1
    {
        if(RTCP event)
        RTCPhandler();
        if(RTP event)
        {
            recvfrom(); //the normal socket api recvfrom
            WritePacketToFile(record_fd)
            {
            //Create new record_fd after 100MB
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

even if it is alright to stick to the single threaded implementation why is the multithreaded approach behaving such a way(not recording after ~15 mins)..?

Comment: And We tried with openRTSP dump feature,starting about 20 instances of openRTSP i.e 20 cameras ..openRTSP also stopped recording in the same way ..

only when we started with 6 openRTSP instances it was going on recording ..